# using PHP frameworks (ZF,...) and ORMs (Doctrine,...) as PHP extensions?

Tags: php, orm, frameworks

Is it possible to use php frameworks (ZF,...) and ORMs (Doctrine,...) as PHP extensions (like [Yaf](http://pecl.php.net/package/yaf))? What is pros and cons of such method?

I want package third party libraries into a single file (like .dll) so it can be easily deployed. Perhaps some performance improvement yielded?

ZF provide a lot of essential classes, how I make my custom build that ZF be a part of PHP language (like .net class library)?
Copying a lot of .php file in library folder of a php app do not seem intuitive.

Comment: as "extensions" can mean quite a few different things, you will have to add some detail to your question.

Comment: If someone implemented it - it would be possible

Comment: @Dagon similar to http://pecl.php.net/package/yaf

Comment: i was expecting an update of more than two words. perhaps why you want this approach, rather than the "standard" way theses frameworks are usually used.

Comment: Extensions are typically written in C. ZF, Doctrine et al are all libraries written in PHP itself. To directly answer your question, probably not.

Comment: Packaging as a DLL would limit you to Windows. Unless you write in C or C++ of course.

Comment: `like .net framework in C#` --- uhm, are you sure you completely understand what exactly is `.net` and what exactly is `c#`?

Comment: @ColeJohnso My concern is packaging not making dll

Comment: @Reza: http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php ?

Comment: @zerkms I mean standard libraries of C#

Comment: @Reza All are using tar balled, then gziped into a `.tgz` or `.tar.gz` file. the difference is that extentions need editing in the `php.ini` file to take effect. Limiting people without access to the file.

Comment: @Reza: there are no "standard libraries of C#". There is `.net` class library, that can be used by any .net language

Comment: @zerkms Oh, Please do not play with words, question is clear!

Comment: @Reza: yes, and I've given a link 4 comments above. http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php Isn't that what you want? PS: just remove anything related to `.net`, it makes no sense in this question

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, It seems relevant, I am reading its docs, is phar files binary? So is it a good practice to use ZF in that format?

Comment: @Reza: "is phar files binary" --- what does it change? "So is it a good practice to use ZF in that format?" --- for what reason? What's wrong with ZF as a .php files?